# Return Contact Only if ALL Contracts are Terminated

Tags: sql-server

Using MS SQL: I have two tables customers and contracts. I want to find active customers that do **NOT** have ANY active contracts. Contracts has a column showing Terminated (1,0)

```
SELECT
contact.FullName,
contract.Terminated,
FROM
dbo.Contact
INNER JOIN Contract ON Contact.ContactId = Contract.ContactId
WHERE
Contact.ContactStatus = 'Active' 
AND Contract.Terminated = 1
```

This returns all contacts and contracts that are "Terminated" (1) but they may have a Contract that is (0). How do I get **ONLY Contacts** that only have Terminated contracts?

Thanks

Comment: The best way is to use EXISTS. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with exists. The following will check that there are no contracts for the contact where Terminated = 0. This will also include contacts that have no rows at all in contract. If that's not what you want you'll need to add another check for that.

```
SELECT
contact.FullName,
FROM Contact
where not exists (
    select 1 from Contract 
    where Contact.ContactId = Contract.ContactId
    and Contract.Terminated = 0
) and
Contact.ContactStatus = 'Active'
```